# How to reverse an array using higher-order functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

Is it possible to reverse an array using higher-order functions. I've searched google and can't find anything on this.

Comment: Is there a reason why arr.reverse() is not sufficient?

Comment: what do you mean with "using higher-order functions"? A higher order function is a function that takes or returns a function. You don't need that to reverse an Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Array.prototype.reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

```
var a = [1,2,3];
console.log(a.reverse());
```